# ¿Como muestro un mensaje de 'No hay resultados'?

Tags: jquery

Tengo un filtro de preguntas en tiempo real con **JQuery**, funciona a la perfección, pero cuando **no haya resultados** de la busqueda necesito añadir un mesaje que lo diga, ej. 'No hay resultados para tu pregunta'

¿Como puedo hacerlo?

```css
.hidden {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="search-project" name="search-project" placeholder="intenta: ¿Como hago mi primera compra?">

<ul class="list-porject">
    <li>¿Como puedo fíar un producto?</li>
    <li>¿Puedo vender mis productos?</li>
    <li>¿Que se puede vender?</li>
    <li>¿Existe la posibilidad de comprar sin tarjeta?</li>
</ul>

<script>
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#search-project").keyup(function(){
   
   // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
   var filter = $(this).val();

   // Loop through the comment list
   $(".list-porject li").each(function(){
    
    // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
    if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
     $(this).addClass('hidden');
    } else {
     $(this).removeClass('hidden');
    }
   });
  });
    })
})(jQuery)
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes crear el mensaje en el html y tenerlo oculto por defecto. Y mostrarlo cuando no hay ninguna coincidencia.

He creado una variable local para saber si ha habido alguna coincidencia o no. Y siempre compruebo si el mensaje es visible pues se oculta.

```css
.hidden {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="search-project" name="search-project" placeholder="intenta: ¿Como hago mi primera compra?">
<p class="no-results hidden">No hay resultados</p>
<ul class="list-porject">
    <li>¿Como puedo fíar un producto?</li>
    <li>¿Puedo vender mis productos?</li>
    <li>¿Que se puede vender?</li>
    <li>¿Existe la posibilidad de comprar sin tarjeta?</li>
</ul>

<script>
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    const noResultsRef = $('.no-results');
    
    $("#search-project").keyup(function() {
      if (!noResultsRef.hasClass('hidden')) {
        noResultsRef.addClass('hidden');
      }
      // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
      var filter = $(this).val();
      let noResults = true;
      // Loop through the comment list
      $(".list-porject li").each(function() {

        // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
          $(this).addClass('hidden');
        } else {
          noResults = false;
          $(this).removeClass('hidden');
        }
      });

      if (filter && noResults) {
        noResultsRef.removeClass('hidden');
      }
    });
  })
})(jQuery)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola pues esta ha sido mi solución, verás he creado un elemento párrafo que le he puesto la clase hidden también.
Luego cuando añades la clase hidden a los elementos de la lista vuelvo a recorrer los elementos li y sumo 1 a una variable contador. Una vez termina de recorrer sale y compara el contador con los elementos li que existen y si contador es mayor muestro el mensaje.

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    let contador = 0;
    let elementos = $(".list-porject li");
    $("#search-project").keyup(function() {
      var filter = $(this).val();
      $(".list-porject li").each(function() {
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
          $(this).addClass('hidden');
          $(".list-porject li").each(function() { //vuelvo a recorrer los li
            if ($(this).hasClass('hidden')) { // si un elemento tiene la clase hidden 
              contador++; //le sumo 1 a contador
            }
          });
          if (contador >= elementos.length) { //si contador es mayor o igual que los elementos li existentes
            $('.vacio').css('display', 'block'); //aplico el estilo es decir hago visible el parrafo con el mensaje
          }
        } else {
          $(this).removeClass('hidden');
        }
      });

    });
  })
})(jQuery)
```

```css
.hidden,
.vacio {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js" integrity="sha256-r/AaFHrszJtwpe+tHyNi/XCfMxYpbsRg2Uqn0x3s2zc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<input type="text" id="search-project" name="search-project" placeholder="intenta: ¿Como hago mi primera compra?">

<ul class="list-porject">
  <li>¿Como puedo fíar un producto?</li>
  <li>¿Puedo vender mis productos?</li>
  <li>¿Que se puede vender?</li>
  <li>¿Existe la posibilidad de comprar sin tarjeta?</li>
  <p class="vacio">No hay resultados.</p>
</ul>
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: La verdad que esta un poco enroscada la solución y no funciona correctamente. Pero! se puede arreglar, a tu respuesta le veo 2 posibles correcciones. Una pista: la variable `contador`

Answer (score 0):

Podrías crear un elemento donde tener el mensaje `No hay resultados.`. Luego, dependiendo si la cantidad de `li` es igual a la cantidad de `li.hidden`, entonces habria que mostrar dicho elemento.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $("#search-project").keyup(function() {

      // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
      var filter = $(this).val();
      var regEx = new RegExp(filter, "i");

      // Loop through the comment list
      $(".list-porject li").each(function() {
        let contains = $(this).text().search(regEx) >= 0;

        // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
        $(this)[contains ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass']('hidden');
      });
      
      // If all nodes are hidden
      let empty = $(".list-porject li").length == $(".list-porject li.hidden").length;
      $('.empty')[empty ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass']('hidden');
    });
  })
})(jQuery)
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="search-project" name="search-project" placeholder="intenta: ¿Como hago mi primera compra?">

<ul class="list-porject">
  <li>¿Como puedo fíar un producto?</li>
  <li>¿Puedo vender mis productos?</li>
  <li>¿Que se puede vender?</li>
  <li>¿Existe la posibilidad de comprar sin tarjeta?</li>
</ul>
<div class="empty hidden">No hay resultados.</div>
```